How to store and use encryption key securely?
I implemented AES 256 CBC to encypt sensitive data. The back end(laravel) and front end(react js) are running in containers using docker.
I would like to store encryption key and use it in front and back securely. For the backend , I decided to use docker secrets. Now I m stuck in front . How can I use encryption key in front without exposing it in code???

You can't – if the encryption operation is going to happen in the browser-based application, then the untrusted end-user environment needs to have a copy of the key, and it'd be possible to extract it from the browser.  Critically, the React application does not run in Docker, even if a container is serving its code, and Docker features can't help here.  Can you use something like a TLS channel to encrypt the data over the wire, and avoid manual crypto operations here?

where do you exacly want to use the key on the react app?

@DavidMaze  I implement end to end encryption so I need to encrypt data in client side before sending the data.

@amacoder in react app I use cryptojs package to encrypt data so I need to pass the key to the encrypt function

i recommend you to create a generation logic. for example from the JWT tokens.
